# Separate Frontend and Backend

Tags: deployment, cross-domain

Before, I used to have my golang backend and frontend be combined where my backend would serve the html. The frontend and backend were combined into one application, and I would point a single type A DNS record. When I would go to example.com/ it would go to my backend which would return the html, and if I went to example.com/apiroute it would also go to my backend which would return a api response. My html and api routes were on the same domain and application.

However, now I want it so that my frontend and backend are separate and are separate applications. For example, I want the static HTML frontend for my project to be hosted on cloudflare pages or some free static web hosting platform. Then, I will have my database and api hosted on my server, or on the cloud. My problem is, I want to visit the website using example.com/ but also be able to connect to my APIs using example.com/apiroute just like I did before. However, I can't point more than one type A DNS record for the same domain. Therefore, if example.com domain is pointing to pages.cloudflare, then I can't also have exampe.com pointing to firebaseendpoint.com.

One solution is to have a subdomain for my API routes, then have the root domain be for the website. So a user would go to example.com for the website, then api.example.com to make requests to my backend. However, I want to know if there is a different way so that it is all on the same domain.

Thanks